# Microdata markup for a website about Hiking

Tags: html, metadata, microdata

I have a webpage that I have been working about hiking in Maine. The menu on the main page lists all the locations (Mountains, Hills,Parks .. etc) we have been to with a link to a page that I supply a review of the specific location, picture gallery, directions to get there, trail maps for the area and other suggestions.

I would love to add Microdata markup to my main page and linked pages to make them more searchable for users specifically looking for places to hike in Maine. I could not find a Microdata "Type" or "Itemprop" That would relate to the "Action" Hiking or a "Review" type possible to state that my pages are reviews or guides for Hiking at certain locations. I would really appreciate a pointer in the right direction to get working on this. PLease Help !

Answer (score 2):

Check schema.org for the available (currently defined) microdata schemas. These might be relevant:

- [Place](https://schema.org/Place)
- [Landform](https://schema.org/Landform)
- [TouristAttraction](https://schema.org/TouristAttraction)

Or you can [propose a new schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581209/schema-org-how-to-extend-a-class/27581768#27581768).