# Schema.org: How to extend a Class or Type

Tags: schema.org, semantic-markup

I have to model a product, which has properties that aren't listed in the Schema.org `Product` type. After seeking in many places, I didn't find anything that fits to my need.
How can I extend the Schema.org `Product` type?

Answer (score 5):

You could always use other vocabularies (that offer the properties you need) in addition to Schema.org. But if you want to use only the vocabulary Schema.org, you have two options in general:

- Propose new properties (or classes).

  You can do this on [Schema.org W3C Community Group](http://www.w3.org/community/schemaorg)’s [mailing list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-schemaorg), or on [Schema.org’s GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues).

  See: [How can I get involved? How can I propose new schemas or other improvements?](https://schema.org/docs/howwework.html#getinvolved)

  If accepted, it might become part of the core (if it’s something "the most common web applications need"), or it might [become an extension](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html).
- (**deprecated!**) Extend existing properties.

  Extending existing properties is documented at http://schema.org/docs/old_extension.html, but note that this mechanism is [considered outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27185362/1591669).

For specific types (including `Product`), you can use Schema.org’s [`additionalProperty`](http://schema.org/additionalProperty) property:

> A property-value pair representing an additional characteristics of the entitity, e.g. a product feature or another characteristic for which there is no matching property in schema.org.

Comment: "Propose new properties" for real? I need an extra property. No problem let me just go through months of standardization process only to see my proposal declined. If it is true that there is no (simple) way to tag on a bunch of extra properties onto existing schema.org types than that reduces the value of the proposal from very high to near zero as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @StijndeWitt: 1) What do you mean with "proposal" in "that reduces the value of the proposal"? 2) You *can* add properties to describe your data: simply use another (or your own) vocabulary in combination with Schema.org. 3) How else could it work? If additions weren’t reviewed/discussed, the vocabulary would certainly become a huge mess. 4) Simple proposals don’t necessarily take "months", some only take days or a few weeks (but others years).

Comment: @unor How would it work at Schema.org’s GitHub issue tracker? Suppose I want to suggest to add `headline` and `alternativeHeadline` properties to the `Event` type - which already are present in the `CreativeWork` type. Would it suffice to give an example url for a real `Event` (say, this one with `url` http://v2.nl/events/deaf-2014), which I would like to give the following properties: `name`= DEAF Biennale 2014; `headline`= The Progress Trap; `alternativeHeadline`= DEAF2014 Dutch Electronic Art Festival - The Progress Trap.

Comment: @iep: Proposals seem to go from one sentence to whole documents. See their docs: [*How can I get involved? How can I propose new schemas or other improvements?*](https://schema.org/docs/howwework.html#getinvolved).