# What Schema.org type to use for personal skills?

Tags: schema.org

I don't know which Schema.org type to use for a specialized team in my work.

I have something like that:

```
team name
team photo
   team member 1 name
   team member 1 photo
   team member 1 qualification/skills
   team member 2 name
   team member 2 photo
   team member 2 qualification/skills
   etc...
```

I could use the type `Organization`, but I don't know what to use to specify the qualification/skills of the person.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each person would be represented by [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person).

You can use all properties that are defined in the first table on that page, i.e., properties from `Person` and [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing).

As you’ll see, there is no property for skills/qualifications.

Depending on your actual case, you might have use for the [`jobTitle` property](http://schema.org/jobTitle). And for a short paragraph of text (which may include information about skills/qualifications) about this person, you could use the [`description` property](http://schema.org/description).

Comment: Is there anyway to recommand a new entry to shema.org ? Because clearly the skills is not a description or a jobtitle. For example engineer will be the jobtitle and chemistry the qualification/skills/speciality.

Comment: @casp: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27581768/1591669) I described how new properties/classes can be proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with using Person schema: itemprop="jobTitle" and itemprop="knows".

Then you may add a link directly to your resume which highlights your skills or About page:

```
<span class="resume" itemprop="knows">
    <a href="https://www.hillwebcreations.com/about-jeannie-hill/" title="About Jeanne" target="_blank" itemprop="url">
    <img src="https://www.hillwebcreations.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/hill-web-creations-Jeannie-Hill.jpg" alt="example of how to add skills via schema" itemprop="url">
    </a>
</span>
```

Recently each page with Person schema came up with a new error stating that it was missing homeLocation. Word from our Google Partners support says these errors in the Search Console will correect themselves and drop off soon. However, for the meantime, I was able to eliminate the error notices by adding the following code:

```
<div itemprop="homeLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<strong>Residence:</strong>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Minneapolis</span>,
<span itemprop="addressCountry" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Country">
  <span itemprop="name">USA</span>
</span>
```

You can find more details as to how on [GitHub](https://github.com/loopasam/schema/blob/master/sample/Restaurant/eclipse/classes/views/tags/schema/Person.html). Or borrow ideas from my own site: [Hill Web Marketing](https://www.hillwebcreations.com/google-releases-new-seo-structured-data-markup/)